# Worpdress cannot create directory

Tags: plugin-development

I have installed a wordpress server locally in mi pc, recentlly I have some issues uploading files using `wordpress media`.

I got some errors like

```
Wordpress cannot create directory `wp-content/uploads/2017/05`. Check permissions in the above directory.
```

I checked directory permissions, and I set up to 777 the entire `wp-content` directory. Also I used `chwon www-data:www-data` to assign properly php user.

I checked php7-fpm conf, and php user is `www-data:www-data`.

I'm using Wordpress 4.7.3 version.

I think I'm missing something, but I don't know what is. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Ismael.

Answer (score 2):

add this below line to your ***wp-config.php*** (if you did not add it yet)

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Check which user run your servers too (not only php7-fpm).

> ps aux|grep nginx
>
> ps aux|grep apache

if your server works on www-data then,

```
cd ../your_wordpress_dir/
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
sudo chmod 640 wp-config.php
```

if you are still getting same error, try a clean installation again with above permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problem in past. Try adding following to your wp-config.php

```
define('FSMETHOD', 'direct');
putenv('TMPDIR='.iniget('uploadstmp_dir'));
```

Let me know if it Helps.